# Get a Drive folder by url in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, drive

I am trying to automate processes from a from. Basically somebody solicits documentatio for a specific client (school). I need the copy of a file created in an existing folder for that shcool. Thing is, when we fill out the solicitation form, we ask for the drive folder url, and I can't seem to get the id from that url, nor access the folder from the url either:

```
    function intialEv() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(lastRow,1,lastRow,11).getValues();
  var folderUrl = data[0][7];
  var date = new Date().getMonth();
  var lang = data[0][8];
  var contact = data[0][10];
  var schoolName = data[0][3];
  var coord = data[0][5];

  // Make a copy of a decoy sheet, setting same name with school and date, copy being created in the destination folder signaled.
  var newSheet = DriveApp.getFileById('1K_QuWNa4OPjlC0S3R76XBILQkqd6kh54hRcXVqruVto').makeCopy("Evaluación Previa_" + schoolName + "_" + date, folderUrl);
```

When I log folderUrl it returns the entire url. Is there a way I can extract the id? Or even more quickly, get the folder in question by url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your folder URLs look like this?

`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzBleEfbQeCuUWs3UFwySTJ7LTf`

If they do, try this:

`const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderUrl.replace(/^.+\//, ''));`

#### Related issue:

- [Add DriveApp.getFileByUrl()](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761537)

#### Reference:

- [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Yes, the url looks axactly like this. I¡ll give it a trt. Thanx

Comment: This worked, Could you explain why? Thanks again!

Comment: `folderUrl` is a text string. The [File.makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination) method expects a `Folder` object rather than a text string. You can get a `Folder` object by extracting the folder ID from the URL and calling `DriveApp.getFolderById()` with that ID.